# Any Port Issue : Python is hanging at STSConnection().get_session_token In server , But Works fine in my laptop

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

When I ran from :Laptop there is no issue but when i ran from my server Which is from my company It hangs at STSConnection().get_session_token

is this tempCredentials = sts_connection.get_session_token  required any ports need to open

```
 import boto
 import datetime
 from datetime import date, timedelta
 import subprocess
 import os
 import argparse
 from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
 from boto.sts import STSConnection
 import shutil





 #command line arguments
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='To create Temp  credentials through STS function and upload to ~/.aws/credentials')

 parser.add_argument('-d', '--device_id', help='acc  xxxxxxxx neumerical value', required=True)
 parser.add_argument('-u', '--user_id', help='user id like xxx  ', required=True)
 parser.add_argument('-p', '--parent_profile', help='parent profile ', required=True)
 parser.add_argument('-m', '--mfa_profile', help='profile', required=True)

 args = parser.parse_args()
  deviceId = args.device_id
  userID   = args.user_id
  parentProfile = args.parent_profile
  mfaProfile = args.mfa_profile



 # Prompt for MFA time-based one-time password (TOTP)
 mfa_TOTP = raw_input("Enter the MFA code: ")

 print "STS connection"
 #sts connection
 sts_connection = STSConnection(profile_name=parentProfile)


 print "STS connection  temp credentials"
 tempCredentials = sts_connection.get_session_token(
    duration=43200,
    mfa_serial_number="arn:aws:iam::" + deviceId + ":mfa/" + userID,
    mfa_token=mfa_TOTP
 )
 print "STS connection  temp credentials closed"

 print str(tempCredentials.access_key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS implements a REST API. This means that port 443 needs to be open for outbound. The return port could be anything from 1024 to 65534.

Try making a normal HTTPS request using wget or curl to a well known web site (https://www.amazon.com) and make sure that this is not being blocked. If this returns a valid web page, then the AWS REST API will be OK.

Double check that you are using the global enpoint for STS. This link will provide you more information. Try `wget https://sts.amazonaws.com` to make sure that the STS endpoint responds.

[Activating and Deactivating AWS STS in an AWS Region](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_enable-regions.html)

And finally don't use your ROOT credentials. Create an IAM user to allocate temporary credentials.

The final solution using boto3:

```
   import boto3
   #sts connection
   session = boto3.Session(profile_name=parentProfile)
   sts_client = session.client('sts')

   tempCredentials = sts_client.get_session_token(
   DurationSeconds=43200,
   SerialNumber="arn:aws:iam::" + deviceId + ":mfa/" + userID,
   TokenCode=mfa_TOTP
   )
   print "STS connection  temp credentials closed"
   print(tempCredentials)
```

Comment: aws sts get-session-token --serial-number arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:mfa/user --token-code 810406 --profile dev-yudw                                                                       with Above command i am able to get the temp credentials                                   and wget https://sts.amazonaws.com
--2017-12-11 22:29:16--  https://sts.amazonaws.com/
Resolving sts.amazonaws.com (sts.amazonaws.com)... 54.239.21.217
Connecting to sts.amazonaws.com (sts.amazonaws.com)|54.239.21.217|:443...  no answer

Comment: One thing that I just noticed. You are using boto (which is old) and not boto3. Here is an example that uses the boto3 library (first released in 2015). http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that your code is using insecure (HTTP port 80) to talk to STS OR something is blocking ports. In your config file add the option debug = 2. This will trace what is happening. https://boto.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.0/boto_config_tut.html